# How to implement web2py password encryption in PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, passwords, web2py, password-encryption

I have a website that I am transforming from web2py to PHP, I am using the website database, so in the PHP site I have a login form that I am using and after the email and password are posted I check the database but I can't get the same encryption as the database password Field in the table auth_user? how can I do the same encryption that web2py dose?

My PHP code is like this, but am using MD5:

```
<?php
// IF The Login Form Was Filled and Submited
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){


// Fetch The Username And Password
$username = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// Use Md5 Hashed Password For Security  
$password_hash = md5($password);

// Check IF The Username and Password was Not Empty . 
if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

  // Selecting The ID for the user with the Posted Credintials .
  $query = "SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password_hash' ";

  // Run The Query
  $query_run = mysql_query($query);

        // Check if the Query Works and return records . 
        if ($query_run){

          // Check if the Query Returns any rows
          $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

          // If the query Dosent return any rows that means that the user credintials is wrong or the user is not registerd
          if ($query_num_rows == 0) {

            echo "<div class='alert alert-error' style='width:300px;margin:0 auto'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><h4>Warning!</h4>Invalid username / password combination</div><br>";

          // If the Query Return a row that means that everyhting is right. 
          } else if ($query_num_rows == 1) {


            // Fetch the user id from the query
            $user_id = mysql_result($query_run, 0 ,'id');

            // Store the user id in the Session
            // Note : The Session is Started in the page Core.inc.php which is included to the index page and has session.start();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;

            // Redirect To index Page , we user here the http_referer 
            //which is coming from the core.inc.php that return the url of the page we came from
            header('Location: ' . '../index.php');


          } else {

            echo "Who The Hell Are you !!";
          }

        // If the Query Didnt Run Retrun mysql Error.
        } else{echo mysql_error();}

// IF The Login Form Was Not Filled . 
} else {


  echo "<div class='alert alert-error' style='width:300px;margin:0 auto'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button><h4>Warning!</h4>Sorry , You must Supply a username and  a password . </div><br>";

}

}

// Print Out Any Other Errors
if(mysql_error()){
echo "Database Error : " . Mysql_error();
}

?>
```

Comment: What ecryption does your site use? We can't know that.

Comment: This is extremely dangerous, a classic path to the SQL injection attack:  $query = "SELECT id FROM auth_user WHERE email='$username' ...   

NEVER EVER EVER DO THIS

Comment: Dear Oleg , this is just for now until i finish the encryption Problem am going to fix it now

Comment: Dear Maerlyn , the encryption is from web2py it self , i cant know what is it exactly , i found something but i dont know how to implement  :                                                     using a salt (token in your example) is a bit primitive and vulnerable 
to cetrain attacks. 

Web2py uses hmac+md5 or hmac+sha512. 

The password can be specified by: 

  auth.settings.hmac_kay='sha512:mypassword' 

which is passed to the validator 

  CRYPT(hmac_key='....') 


Massimo 

The prefix:  (sha512) specifies the algorithm.

Comment: Lol nobody wants theire password to be encrypted..... USE HASH!!

Comment: I have Data Already in the database , and that database was already running wit web2py , so i need to figure it out ..

Comment: Then do you need decrypt with php the passwords crypted with web2py only?

Comment: Dear Christin  , yes  or if i can do the same crypted done by web2py and then compare it the the passwords in the database